# Choosing numbers with the sum $S$

Tags: combinatorics

Supose we have numbers $0,1,2,3,4,...,2k-1$

How many ways are there to chose $k$ of those numbers such that:

1. The sum of chosen numbers is $S\\$
2. For every $c; -1<c<2k$: at least half of numbers $0,1,2,3,4,...,c$ were chosen

I was solving the problem of how many structures like the one on the picture below can be made out of $N$ bricks.

[image]

It turns out, that solving this problem woud be very easy if i knew the solution to the first problem.

Comment: What's the source of this question, please?

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
It turns out there are $f(N)$ structures like the one on the picture above.
And the answer to the question in the title is similar to $j(2k,k,S)$, but without the factor inside the big brackets in the recursive formula.

$f$, $j$ and the starting conditions are defined below.

[image]

[image]